# NHibernate SchemaUpdate still wants to recreate table

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2012, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with Fluent on my SQL Server 2012 and I've decided to use SchemaUpdater instead of SchemaExport becouse I dont want my data to disappear. I've created method like this:

```
 public void UpdateSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        System.Action<string> updateExport = x =>
        {
            using (var file = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\tmp\update.sql", System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
            {
                sw.Write(x);
                sw.Close();
            }
        };
        NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate SchemaUpdater = new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate(config);
        SchemaUpdater.Execute(updateExport, true); 

    }
```

My database is creating but when i want to add new field to my model i get an error:`"Invalid column name 'xxx'.
↵Invalid column name 'xxx'."`

I've decided to debug and check SchemaUpdater.Exceptions, there was:

```
Count = 4
[0]: {"There is already an object named 'User' in the database."}
[1]: {"There is already an object named 'FK5E008E27F9F9FA61' in the database.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}
[2]: {"There is already an object named 'FK5E008E27194964AD' in the database.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}
[3]: {"There is already an object named 'FK5E008E27713F97F9' in the database.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}
```

This looks like program wants still to create new table, not to update it, sql which is created and sent to db:

```
create table [User] (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   Acount NVARCHAR(255) null,
   Email NVARCHAR(255) null,
   (...)
   xxx NVARCHAR(255) null,
   Manager_id INT null,
   Evaluator_id INT null,
   WorkTimeAdmin_Id INT null,
   primary key (Id)
)
alter table [User] 
    add constraint FK5E008E27F9F9FA61 
    foreign key (Manager_id) 
    references [User]
alter table [User] 
    add constraint FK5E008E27194964AD 
    foreign key (Evaluator_id) 
    references [User]
alter table [User] 
    add constraint FK5E008E27713F97F9 
    foreign key (WorkTimeAdmin_Id) 
    references [User]
```

I really want an automated solution, so no copying and editing sql's
any ideas what should i change?

Answer (score 1):

You never need to run SchemaUpdate explicitly. The Configuration instance can take a property "hbm2ddl.auto" (NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Hbm2ddlAuto), that, when set to "update" (SchemaAutoAction.Update), will update the database if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ricardo's answer, here's an example of how the hbm2ddl.auto property is set. The "update" instructs the Session Factory to create tables that don't exist and update existing ones if schema and relative model are different. I learnt the hard way that "update" is case sensitive, so "Update" doesn't work.

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => {
                    cfg.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "update"); // Updates or creates tables                                                
                })
```

Comment: ExceptionMessage: "Invalid column name 'MyProperty2'.
↵Invalid column name 'MyProperty2'."
ExceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" - Any ideas?

Comment: Is this occurring during session factory initialization or while performing a query through Fluent Nhibernate?

Comment: While performing a query :)

Comment: Does the "MyProperty2" has a NotNull constraint? Because the SchemaUpdater is not able to add a column with a not-null constraint to an existing table (for existing-data reasons). Which would also explain why it's trying to recreate the table.

Comment: No, it is set as public virtual int? MyProperty {get;set;} and in map it's .Nullable()

Comment: Apologies for the number of questions. I'm just trying to get to the bottom of the issue. Re-reading your post I noticed that your sql output "create table [User]" has the User table in square brackets. Is the mapping defining the table name within square brackets? If this is the case, can you test your code with a mapping that doesn't contain square brackets in the table name?